# Automatically get URL of a site displaying my image?

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-headers, bbcode, hotlinking

I've been trying to get the URL (including GET parameters) of a site that is displaying my image. This is because I want to extract one parameter of the URL.

A friend told me that she knew someone that could achieve this, but I don't know if he was doing it with an image. Also I don't think I can do it with a link because when going to external sites it will appear a warning page saying that you're being redirected outside, so if I put a link to my page and someone clicks, I will get the referrer URL of redirection warning page. I can't assure if my friend was telling the truth about this, but it's very likely that it was true.

All I could get with the image was the IP and other things of the HTTP header, but the referrer part is empty and I thought that the referrer contained the full URL I'm talking about.

This is what I have tried.
First the img tag in the other site in BBCode:

```
[img]http://______.com/get_image.php?i=myimage[/img]
```

And in my site this script in PHP, although any language that does the work would be good for me:

```
<?php
// Get name of image to be displayed (non-sanitized here for simplicity)
$filename = $_GET["i"];

// Here I want to get the site where image is being viewed
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
        $visitor_url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
} else {
        $visitor_url = "none";
}

// And write the referrer to a file just to test if it works
$fp = fopen('referer.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $visitor_url);
fclose($fp);

// Eventually display the image
header('Content-Type: image/png');
readfile($filename . '.png');
?>
```

So my questions are:

1. Is it possible to get full URL of a site that is displaying my image?
2. If not, is there any other method to get the full URL?

Thank you in advance.

Note: I don't have any permision in the other site where I'm posting the image, I'm just an user there. Please tell me if I'm missing something or I have to ask this in another way, I'm new to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by switching my site (where image is hosted) to **HTTPS**. The code in my question was doing its job correctly.

It looks that `HTTP_REFERER` was blank because of it coming from an HTTPS site and my site being HTTP it would always send it blank. I was aware that it could be a problem, but didn't make much sense for me because *`HTTP_REFERER` was also blank when coming from another HTTP site* (which I think it's not normal) so I thought the error was in another place.

Usually `HTTP_REFERER` is sent when it comes from and goes to:

1. from HTTP to HTTP
2. from HTTPS to HTTPS
3. from HTTP to HTTPS

But it's **not** sent when it comes from and goes to:

1. from HTTPS to HTTP

And in my case, I don't know why, it **wasn't** being sent from HTTP to HTTP which was confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

Try `REMOTE_HOST` instead of `HTTP_REFERER`:

```
// Here I want to get the site where image is being viewed
if (!empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'])) {
    $visitor_url = $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'];
} else {
    $visitor_url = "none";
}
```

The web server where you are serving the image will need to be configured properly. If using Apache, this is with `HostNameLookups On`.

See http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: I have just tried this. It's giving me the hostname of the user, eg.: _*.red-*-*-*.dynamicip.rima-tde.net_ (numbers replaced by asterisk).

Comment: Remote host contains the client (or proxy) IP. The only case where this would work is if the other site is also downloading the image - or in other words - acting as a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Normally browsers are sending full referer with all URL components including query parameters - `$_GET` params. If they don't then there is no other way to achieve that URL while passing throught an image content.

Sometimes sending referer may be blocked, for eg. in some batch URL processing using some crawler like program/script or on some proxies.

In PHP receiving referer is done by `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` because it's normally just http header from request and it's the only `$_SERVER` array key with referer info.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe it was possible before in the site I'm trying and now is no longer possible because they blocked sending referer like you said.

Answer (score 0):

You added the `.htaccess` tag so I think you're using the Apache web server. If you'd like to prevent the issue entirely, you can disable hotlinking entirely by going one layer lower. Instead of managing in PHP, you can configure the web server to not serve content to domains other than the one you are hosting.

Check out the [guide](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DisableImageHotLinking) for more details.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Apache. What I wanted to do is the opposite: get information thanks to the hotlinking, more accurately what I want is the URL where a user is viewing the image.